# GDAL Python - How I can determine the PROJ version used

Tags: python, gdal, proj

As PROJ recent major update introduces importants change in the API, I need in my script to check what is the PROJ version compiled with the current GDAL installation of the user. I know I can get the GDAL version with `osgeo.gdal.VersionInfo()` but it does not tell me what is the PROJ version.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This way:

```
>>> from osgeo import osr
>>> osr.GetPROJVersionMajor()
6
>>> osr.GetPROJVersionMinor()
2
```

Comment: That method doesn't exist for `osgeo.version_info` : `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=9, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

Comment: @Spacedman I have `osgeo.version_info sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)` and method works. My current Proj version seems to be 6.3. Newest Proj is 7.2 but I do not know if there has been changes between 6 and 7.

Comment: I have Python 3.5.3, and after `pip install osgeo` (no errors), then `from osgeo import osr` returns an error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'osr'`. Also, I don't know which osgeo version was installed by pip: `osgeo.__version__` returns an `AttributeError: module 'osgeo' has no attribute '__version__'`

Answer (score 1):

I found this was necessary (python 3.9)

```
> import osgeo
> osgeo.version_info

sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=13, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

> import osgeo.osr
> osgeo.osr.GetPROJVersionMajor()

9
> osgeo.osr.GetPROJVersionMinor()

0
```