# Return used transformation from GDAL warp (or similar)

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, well-known-text, pyproj

I would like to identify/confirm the transformation used when reprojecting a raster with gdalwarp (or gdal.warp in python).

I already tried to find possible transformations with pyproj.Transformer, export the coordinate operation as wkt2 and hand it over to gdalwarp´s -ct argument but I get different results.

Is there a way to export or access the coordinate operation selected by GDAL?

EDIT: According to https://gdal.org/tutorials/osr_api_tut.html GDAL doesn´t know which transformation will be used until the transformation is actually performed! And even then I can´t find a way to look up which transformation was actually used:

> OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation() under-the-hood may determine several candidate coordinate operations transforming from the source CRS to the target CRS. Those candidate coordinate operations each have their own area of use. When Transform() is invoked, it will determine the most appropriate coordinate operation based on the coordinates of the point to transform and area of use.

Is there really no way to get this info?

Comment: Warping rasters is more complicated than converting plain coordinates. Maybe you can find some useful information from http://jgomezdans.github.io/gdal_notes/reprojection.html.

Comment: I wouldn´t mint using point coordinates, as long as i can find out the transformation used to go from the specified source CRS to the destination CRS.

Comment: The source code is at https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/alg/gdaltransformer.cpp and there seems to be some comments.

Comment: It seems that the final transformation is not between the source crs and target crs, but between pixel coordinates and target crs. Source crs is used as one input parameter when this transformation is computed. "The trickiest part of using the function is ensuring that the transformer created is from source file pixel/line coordinates to output file georeferenced coordinates."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that gdalwarp lets Proj to select the most suitable transformation so you should get information about it with projinfo. Make sure that projinfo and GDAL are using the same Proj version and possible gridshift files. However, that's probably the same info that you get with pyproj.Transformer.

About how to find the Proj version see [GDAL Python - How I can determine the PROJ version used](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346803/gdal-python-how-i-can-determine-the-proj-version-used)

```
projinfo -s epsg:4326 -t epsg:3857
Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

EPSG:3856, Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator, 0 m, World.

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad
  +step +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84

WKT2:2019 string:
CONVERSION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator",
    METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
        ID["EPSG",1024]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8801]],
    PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8802]],
    PARAMETER["False easting",0,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8806]],
    PARAMETER["False northing",0,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8807]],
    ID["EPSG",3856]]
```

Comment: Thanks, that is one way to go, although it is still prone to errors I guess. GDAL would have to return the transformation "choice" it got from proj to know for sure. It does surprise me a bit that this question has not come up more often in the past.