# Reprojecting from BNG to WGS84 using python gdal.Warp causes a shift in the Channel Islands (Guernsey and Jersey)

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, shift

I use the following python code to reproject from British National Grid to WGS84 a raster dataset that covers Great Britain, Isle of Man, Guernsey and Jersey:

```
output = path output tif file
input = path to input tif file
raster = gdal.Open(input)
    
gdal.Warp(output, raster, format='GTiff', srcSRS='EPSG:27700',       \
dstSRS='EPSG:4326', multiThread=True, xRes=0.000045, yRes=0.000045,  \
srcNodata=255, dstNodata=255, warpMemoryLimit=65536000,              \
targetAlignedPixels=True, creationOptions=['COMPRESS=LZW',           \
'BIGTIFF=YES']
```

I have been using this piece of code for some years and never had any problem. However, it is now causing a shift of several hundred meters in the Channel islands.

I reinstalled anaconda and all packages recently, so I assume the latest versions of gdal use a different geographic transformation perhaps??

Comment: I'm not sure that BNG covers the Channel Islands, so you might need to use a different projection

Comment: Isle of Guernsey https://epsg.io/102070

Comment: My point is that a dataset in BNG covering GB, Isle of Man and Channel Islands was being reprojected to WGS84 by gdal with no issues at all until now. What has changed in gdal and how can I overcome that change?

Answer (score 0):

Test with projinfo (Proj Rel. 9.2.1, June 1st, 2023) shows that this version of Proj prefers to use a gridshift file

```
projinfo -s epsg:27700 -t epsg:4326

-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

unknown id, Inverse of British National Grid + OSGB36 to WGS 84 (9), 1 m, United Kingdom (UK) - offshore to boundary of UKCS within 49deg45'N to 61N and 9W to 2E; onshore Great Britain (England, Wales and Scotland). Isle of Man onshore.

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +inv +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000
        +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy
  +step +proj=hgridshift +grids=uk_os_OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.tif
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
```

Maybe your installation is missing the file "uk_os_OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.tif"

Comment: What is that tif file for? How can I check whether I have it or not? 
I'm afraid I don't understand the "projinfo" comment. What does your comment about gridshift file entail?

Comment: Proj is the library that GDAL is using for coordinate operations. Projinfo shows what the Proj library is going to do when you ask it to make a transformation EPSG:27700->EPSG:4326. Grid shift files are used for making local correction to transformation results which are obtained with a plain mathematical formula. See https://proj.org/en/9.2/operations/transformations/hgridshift.html. The gridshift files are installed into a directory that is defined by an environmental variable PROJ_DATA (or PROJ_LIB with older Proj versions.).

Comment: I see. But any ideas as to how should I be using gdal.Warp to reproject a dataset in BNG covering GB, IoM and Channel islands to WGS84 without causing a shift in Channel islands? (Last time I run my script without issues was Dec 2022, so I assume later versions of gdal must have changed something)

Comment: Please give coordinates in EPSG:27700 from one point in your area, and correct result in EPSG:4326. It may be that the Proj installation in your Anaconda environment is not perfect for your GDAL version. With test data others can make a test with their installation.

Comment: Coordinates in BNG (352437E 488725N) should become something like (2.656376W, 49.458081N) in WGS84

Comment: Are you sure about the coordinates? I am getting `-2.73221243857031 54.291920992281` and the MapTiler converter gives a result that differs in longitude at 6th decimal place  https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=27700&t_srs=4326&ops=7710&x=352437.0000000&y=488725.0000000.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Coordinates in BNG (352437, -48872) -that's x and y- should become something like (2.656376W, 49.458081N) in WGS84

Comment: The result is `-2.65638329219551 49.4580862066527` with current GDAL using Proj version `Rel. 9.2.1, June 1st, 2023`. I do have the gridshift file. I used GDAL that is installed with the OSGeo4W installer on Windows.

Comment: That result seems correct. What should I then do to get this right in python?

Comment: If you do not have the gridshift file in your Proj data directory, then add it from https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ-data/tree/master/uk_os.  Check also what Proj version you have https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346803/gdal-python-how-i-can-determine-the-proj-version-used.

Comment: My Proj versions are: Major:9 and Minor:2. I can't find a Proj folder in my gdal installation at all though. However, I seem to have found a solution to the problem by using a gsb file.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution to the problem using a gsb file (OSTN15_NTv2OSGBtoETRS.gsb).

gsb_file = Path to OSTN15_NTv2OSGBtoETRS.gsb

srcSRS = '+init=EPSG:27700 +nadgrids=' + gsb_file